# Insert null in one column on two columns same value in Oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle

i have inserted value from one table to another and i want to check if two columns values are same in a row insert null in one column of another table(table in which i am inserting values. In my example it is table1).
My existing query is given as follows how should i convert it according to my requirement.

```
INSERT INTO table1    (date1,date2)
SELECT substr(numtodsinterval(MAX(date1)-MIN(date2),'day'),
12,8)  
FROM table2 where ....;
```

Comment: can you be more clear ?

Comment: an example will help.